# Unable to attach certain file types to MoinMoin page?

Tags: moinmoin

I configured a a local MoinMoin server and am trying to attach an excel file to a page. Upload for cpp, ods and txt files works fine but pdf, exe, doc, xls and xlsx files DON'T get attached. Once I click the 'upload' button, I get redirected back to the wiki page. When I go back to the Attachments sections I don't see the file attached to the page.

(Running MoinMoin 1.9.3 + Apache2.2 on Windows XP.)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
It seems to be an issue only when moin python scripts are called as CGI scripts. I switched to using WSGI in Apache (following instructions from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithMoinMoin) and am able to upload any file.